# Map over data frame columns, apply function to data if column meets condition

Tags: r, google-analytics

I'm pulling data from the Google Analytics API, processing it locally, then knitting an .Rmd file into text, tables, and visualisations. As part of the knitting/tabling process, I'm doing some basic formatting (e.g. rounding off percentages and adding % signs).

For this question, I have `toPercent()`, which works fine if used like this:

```
toPercent <- function(percentData){
    percentData <- round(data, 2)
    percentData <- mapply(toString, percentData)
    percentData <- paste(percentData, "%", sep="")
}

devices <- toPercent(devices$avgSessionDuration)
```

However, manually setting the function for every table is time-intensive. I created the `percentCheck()` to look for columns that matched my criteria:

```
percentCheck <- function(data){
    data[,grep("rate|percent", names(data), ignore.case=TRUE)] <- toPercent(data[,grep("rate|percent", names(data), ignore.case=TRUE)])
}

devices <- percentCheck(devices)
```

But I know this doesn't work on a dataset with multiple matches (e.g. a column for `exitRate` and a column for `bounceRate`).

**Q1:** Have I written `toPercent()` in a way that won't return multiple values to one entry?

**Q2:** How can I structure `percentCheck()` to map over the dataset and only apply `toPercent()` if the column name includes a given string?

**Version/Packages:**

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10) -- "Sock it to Me"
library(rga)
library(knitr)
library(stargazer)
```

**Data:**

```
> dput(devices)
structure(list(deviceCategory = c("desktop", "mobile", "tablet"
), sessions = c(817, 38, 1540), avgSessionDuration = c(153.424888853179, 
101.942758538617, 110.270988142292), bounceRate = c(39.0192297391397, 
50.2915625371891, 50.1343873517787), exitRate = c(25.3257456030279, 
32.0236280487805, 29.0991902834008)), .Names = c("deviceCategory", 
"sessions", "avgSessionDuration", "bounceRate", "exitRate"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification:

```
percentCheck <- function(data){
  idx  <- grepl("rate|percent", names(data), ignore.case=TRUE)
  data[idx] <- lapply(data[idx], function(x) paste0(sprintf("%.2f", round(x,2)), "%"))
  return(data)
}
```

Here, I first used `grepl` to create and index of columns which meet the specified criteria. Then, this index is used in `lapply` to apply it to all these columns and the function that is applied is similar to your `toPercent` function, only I found it a bit more compact like this.

Now you can apply it to your whole data set in one go:

```
percentCheck(devices)
#  deviceCategory sessions avgSessionDuration bounceRate exitRate
#1        desktop      817           153.4249     39.02%   25.33%
#2         mobile       38           101.9428     50.29%   32.02%
#3         tablet     1540           110.2710     50.13%   29.10%
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm building more formatting function for different GA data types, and this seems to be accepting those other functions without a hitch. Speaking of, do you know of any good beginner's tutorials for *apply() in R?

Comment: You can definitely have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega/7141669#7141669 and for more, I would just google and/or check out the basic R tutorials like http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf. Personally, I would advise to start learning `apply`, `sapply` and `lapply` and only after that the others like `mapply` `vapply` `tapply` etc.